# MSSQL 2017 Standard edition download

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to test MSSQL 2017 standard edition but couldn't find any link for trial. I did download developer edition but It is replica of Enterprise edition.

I am trying to test some functionalities on Basic availability groups which only exists on the standard edition.

Comment: Microsoft does not provide ISOs to the Standard edition unless you have a license to it.

Comment: so I have to pay without trying first, awesome MS.

Comment: SQL Server 2017 is a product you must pay.  They give out trials to the Enterprise version since, based on my experience with SQL Server, has *most* the features of the other editions of it.  They also have Express which is of course free.

Comment: Basic availability groups doesn't exists in the enterprise edition.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use advanced availability and just configure it as you would have if you had access only to basic availability?  Considering,  basic availability has a limited subset of the feature advanced availability everything you can do with  basic should be possible with advanced.

Comment: I am trying to setup 8 database and 8 availability groups, each for one database but on advanced, its just merges databases on one listener, I am assuming that because advanced mode but can't be sure. so I am trying if I can do this on basic or not, very hard without having practical experience on differences between basic and advanced availability groups.

Comment: Read the differences between basic and advanced.  If you want 8 then setup 4 individual groups of 2 which is the limitation of basic if my memory serves me (read the differences over 3 hours ago)

Comment: I ran across this because I was trying to install a new instance of a server that was already installed in production.  Trying to just create a new instance requires the install media which was not saved on the local machine (from what I can tell).  I can't even search the server for the install file(s) because I can't find the EXE name of that on the web.  What a pain.  No idea if this would work or not... https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2017-rtm